# Zebra KBTools MC92N0 Keyboard Remapping C++ -- "error.h" no such file or directory

Tags: c++, keyboard, include, windows-ce, barcode-scanner

I want to remapp the Keyboard of a Zebra MC92N0 with Windows CE.
I downloaded the KB Tool for the MC92 from the Zebra Support Page and opened it with Visual Studio 2013.
After rebuilding the Project I became the following error:
"error C1083: File(Include) could not be opened: "error.h": No such file or directory"
`#include <stdio.h>`
**`#include <error.h>`**
`#include "makebins.h"`

I searched for a while but I can't find the 'error.h' file.
I also searched in other remapping projects with the same result.

Comment: Please check if it is really a Visual Studio 2013 project. Aren't we stuck in developing only in VS2008 with windows mobile?

Comment: @etalon11 thanks for the fast answer. You're right I've just forgot it, I will test asap.

Comment: @etalon11 that has solved my problem thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is in the comments:

> Please check if it is really a Visual Studio 2013 project. Aren't we stuck in developing only in VS2008 with windows mobile? – etalon11 1 hour ago

Thanks @etalon11!